# Cancel PC shutdown - without time period

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd, shutdown

I'm familiar with `shutdown /a` or `-a`, but it only works if there is a timer before shut down.

Is there a way for me be to write a batch file which will stop the shutdown process even if the user will shutdown manually?

Comment: When I Google `windows prevent shutdown` I get a lot of results, do none of them work for you?

Comment: all im getting is this type : 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe -a '

but as i said, its working only when the shutdown is being done by a timer, or an alarm like shutdown -s -t 200 

i cant use that to stop the shutdown when im pressing the shutdown button via windows gui ..

Comment: I think you can - you just have to run it quickly enough, while the shutdown is running. What is your situation exactly, can you add a bit more detail? It is, for example, possible for administrators to prevent non-admin users from shutting down the machine, using the Registry. Is that not an option?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thanks ,i didnt know that :) but its not what im looking for.

i want to write a batch file, when im pressing the 'shutdown' button - it will go into 'sleep' mode instead. and for that, i first need to stop the shutdown procces, and i just cant find the solution online.

Comment: You want the batch file to run *automatically* when the button is pressed? Not sure that is even possible

Comment: I wrote before a vbscript that ask you a `(VbYes/VbNo)` question with a msgbox for shutdown ! if you want to take a look at this vbscript, just add the tag `Vbscript`  and i will post it to you !

Comment: I think its possibile via ' time scheduler' on windows. but thanks you so much for your answers :)

@Hackoo im pretty new here so i hope i did what you asked me to. any way ill be happy to see the script thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This vbscript can create a shortcut to your Desktop asking you if you want to hibernate your computer.

And of course, you can change it for a reboot or for a shutdown.

```
Option Explicit
Dim MyScriptPath 
MyScriptPath = WScript.ScriptFullName
Call Shortcut(MyScriptPath,"Hibernate the computer")
Call AskQuestion()
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Shortcut(PathApplication,Name)
    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    MyTab = Split(PathApplication,"\")
    If Name = "" Then
        Name = MyTab(UBound(MyTab))
    End if
    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\" & Name & ".lnk")
    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(PathApplication)
    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "%SystemRoot%\system32\SHELL32.dll,-28"
    objShortCut.Save
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub AskQuestion()
    Dim Question,Msg,Title
    Title = "Hibernate the computer by Hackoo 2016"
    Msg = "Are you sure to Hibernate the computer now ?"& Vbcr &_
    "If yes, then click [YES] button "& Vbcr &_
    "If not, then click [NO] button"
    Question = MsgBox (Msg,VbYesNo+VbQuestion,Title)
    If Question = VbYes then
        Call Run_Hibernate()
    else
        WScript.Quit()
    End if
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Run_Hibernate()
    Dim ws,Command,Execution
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Command = "Cmd /c %windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Hibernate"
    'Command = "Cmd /c Shutdown -s -t "& N &" -c "& DblQuote("Save your work because your PC will shut down in "& N &" seconds")
    Execution = ws.run(Command,0,True)
End sub
'**********************************************************************************************
```